# System.EntryPointNotFoundException error in SWIG on mono 2.8

Tags: c#, mono, swig

I asked about an error for running Swig examples on mono 2.8 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907041/swig-mono-c-example-errors-of-not-finding-the-library).

Adding "-arch i386" solved the issue with simple example, but when I tried to run the other examples, I got the following error, for example, with Examples/csharp/variables :

```
Unhandled Exception: System.EntryPointNotFoundException: CSharp_ivar_set
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) examplePINVOKE:ivar_set (int)
  at example.set_ivar (Int32 value) [0x00000] in :0 
  at runme.Main () [0x00000] in :0
```

There seems to be no problem in reading ivar_set.

```
Mono: Searching for 'CSharp_ivar_set'.
Mono: Probing 'CSharp_ivar_set'.
Mono: Probing 'CSharp_ivar_set'.
Mono: Probing 'CSharp_ivar_setA'.
Mono: Probing 'CSharp_ivar_setA'.
```

[examplePINVOKE.cs](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/10773282/2010/examplePINVOKE2.cs) has the  [DllImport("example", EntryPoint="CSharp_ivar_set")] at line 191.

What might be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting up

```
export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=
```

solves this issue.

I got this hint from [mhutch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907041/swig-mono-c-example-errors-of-not-finding-the-library/3910713#3910713).